# Which software installer plugin for Apache Maven do you recommend?

Tags: java, installation, maven, maven-plugin

For Apache Maven I have found a [izpack plugin](http://izpack.codehaus.org/izpack-maven-plugin/) and a [NSIS plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/nsis/) (for Win32).

Are there other Maven plugins available which allow to create software installers for Java applications, or are these the most popular and 'mature' tools?

It does not have to include a pretty GUI, even a simple command line installer could be helpful enough. Support for file permissions (executable flag for shell scripts) would be nice to have so that users on Linux don't have to set this flag manually.

Answer (score 0):

If GUI is not an issue, you may want to look at [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)